# BlazeDS can't change polling interval

Tags: java, apache-flex, coldfusion, blazeds

I'm trying to change the polling interval on a BlazeDS channel configuration but the client always seems to get the messages in batches of 3. I'm testing sending 1 message per second. The server is running Tomcat with Railo. The message flow goes something like this (I didn't design it but I'm mostly stuck with this design):

1. Python -> ColdFusion Webservice
2. ColdFusion -> Java ServiceAdapter / MessageBroker
3. Flex subscribe to BlazeDS

I think I've tracked down the channel-definition in the services-config.xml because if I comment it out, the client can't connect. The client is using a subscribe to get the messages. I've tried mixing and matching config settings with no luck.

```
 <channel-definition id="cf-polling-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
        <endpoint uri="https://{server.name}:{server.port}{context.root}/flex2gateway/cfamfpolling" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
            <polling-interval-seconds>0</polling-interval-seconds>
            <polling-interval-millis>0</polling-interval-millis>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

I would really like to change this to long polling but I'm trying to just change a single configuration and I can't even get that to work. The server will only have a small number of users (<20).

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.